# Webview content not showing

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview to open following agreement page link

I am using following code to render this. I have tried with different kind of other webview properties as well.

PS this page is rendering successfully in all kind of browsers and in iOS Webview as well.

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    webView.loadUrl(AppConstants.AGREEMENT_URL);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            showProgressBar();
            webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
            hideProgressBar();
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
            //Your code to do

        }


    });
```

Comment: remove all properties and settings (such as `webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`) then try to see if it works. If it does, then enable the settings back _one by one_

Comment: also, check if onPageCommitVisible is actually being called. You set your webview invisible in onPageStarted

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement onReceivedSslError in this manner and let me know

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
        handler.proceed();
    }
});
```

However I tried to implement that and works perfectly for me :(

```
    var webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.wvWebView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    webView.loadUrl("http://ec2-35-177-120-23.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/page/agreement");
```

The WebView has match parent? Internet permissions are ok? Try to se a red background to the webview: can you see it?

Comment: THanks for your answer , onReceivedSslError not being called.

Comment: Thanks it seems like issue was with height. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You try this:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("http://ec2-35-177-120-23.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/page/agreement");
```

In manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer , it is loading Pinterest page but still page mentioned in question not loading. I am not sure where does the issue is. Like I mentioned it is loading in iOS in webview and all other web browsers but not rendering in webview android. I am not sure what am I missing.

Comment: You can change pinterest to your url, I have tested with your url and it works.